# How to send specific object to Google Analytics to display in table for the website's owner?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics

I need to send object like this

```
{adId: $adId, adName: $adName, OwnerId: $OwnerId, viewerId: $viewerId}
```

from Angular to google analytics, to display these data for specific view in my website.
**

- > -How could i handle google analytics to display the table with data?
- > -How could i send these data from angular side?

Comment: Welcome to stack please check the tags you are using rather than just adding everything.  Google analytics api is for extracting data **from** Google analytics and google analytics v4 is for **mobile tracking** neither of which you appear to be using.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send that object into GA and have it usable in any meaningful way, but you can create some custom dimensions and pass each value through.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

Custom attributes (Dimensions and Metrics) can be exposed in normal GA reports one at a time, or you can make a custom report to show whatever information it is you might need, for example total hits by OwnerId or adId.